# Replacing a Hx711 load cell ADC with ADS1256

Tags: arduino, adc, hx711

I bought a set of [this 1kg load cell and Hx711 ACD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00QC6M45A) and it works great. Unfortunately the Hx711 ADC only offers 80SPS which is to slow for my application. I want keep the load cell and replace the Hx711 with an [ADS1256](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1256.pdf?ts=1684077406381&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FADS1256) It is wired it up the following way. The code comes from [this example](https://curiousscientist.tech/ads1256-custom-library). the relevant part that I am using is this:

```
    A.setDRATE(DRATE_300000SPS);  //Set speed to 300000 SPS
    A.setMUX(DIFF_0_1);           // set differential measuring: Din0 +Din1
    A.setPGA(PGA_64);             // set gain amp. to 64
    A.sendDirectCommand(SELFOCAL); // set offset
    A.sendDirectCommand(SYSOCAL);  // set offset

    while (Serial.read() != 's')  //The conversion is stopped by a character received from the serial port
    {
      Serial.println(A.convertToVoltage(A.readSingleContinuous()), 20);
    }
    A.stopConversion();
    break;
```

I encountered two problems though:

**1. Weak signal**
The difference in voltage between an unloaded load cell and when I place 1kg is only 1.6mV. The maximum voltage range with 64 gain amplification on the ADS1256 is +-78mv. I guess I need further amplification or is the wiring wrong? I have this [signal amplifier](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0B711R65K?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details). Can I use it to amplify the positive and negative Signal (white and green wire) at the *same* time?

**2. random  spikes in the signal**
at data rates over 100SPS the signal has random spikes, at higher speeds there are even more spikes. I am not sure how and why there are happening. The spikes drop or jump the the same value though..
[image: spikes in data]

[image: wiring ADS1256]

Comment: The chip used in the amplifier  you suggest has a fair bit (like 100x) as much drift as either the AVIA or the TI chip, and the packaged amplifier could be worse. Up to you to decide if that's material in  your application, it's still pretty low. Are  you sure your Arduino, whatever version it might be, is up  to handling that high a data rate?

Comment: Are you sure that the Arduino supply does not interfere with the voltage "references" and ADC range of the ADS1256?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany hm I thought this chip ( LM358) is regularly used for strain gauges. What would be a better alternative? 
+I will try a more powerful micro controller, e.g. teensy. it should handle the data

Comment: @Antonio51 No, i am not sure. Currently it is powerd by usb. What do I have to do to prevent interference?

Comment: The link you supplied claims an AD620 is used. I've seen ads for amplifiers using the LM358 which is more like 1000x worse than AVIA or TI chip- it's just a cheap as chips op-amp that is not considered 'precision' in any way. It's possible to use it for a strain gauge with an external auto-zero circuit but it won't be great.  You can look at "zero drift" op-amps and inamps but pay attention to the noise over the bandwidth you are using.

Comment: Ok. See well figures 25 and 26 of the datasheet.

Comment: @konrad I am experiencing the same issue as you. Were you able to find a solution?